# pandas installation - numpy version is too old

Tags: python, linux, pandas, installation, rhel

At my workplace, I use a Virtual Machine (VM) with a better hardware setup than my laptop to work with data (cleaning, organizing, analysis, etc.).  I am trying to install Pandas from source (i.e., tar.gz) because the VM is locked down (i.e., it does not have access to hosts outside the company network). I receive the following error when I try to build and install pandas from its source directory:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python setup.py install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 606, in <module>
    **setuptools_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 245, in fetch_build_eggs
    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 550, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (numpy 1.4.1 (/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.6.1'))
```

However, when I enter the Python shell, import numpy, and check its version, I receive the following output:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.9.0'
```

The VM is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) with Python 2.6.6 (path is  `/usr/bin/python`). I have sudo access on the VM. I have been able to install modules in the past (e.g., pyodbc) by downloading them on my Windows laptop, using WinSCP to copy files to the VM, and then installing from source on the VM.

How should I begin to remedy this dependency issue?

Comment: It looks like there is a difference between

    `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages`

and

    `/usr/bin/python`

It also looks like for some reason pandas is being pointed to the first, and not the second.

Is there a way you can force pandas to see the first environment?

Comment: you don't need admin privileges to install anaconda or even just the conda package manager. that's route i would take.

Comment: I just checked Anaconda and it requires at least Python 2.7. I'm still going to attempt to install Pandas with an underlying Python 2.6.6, but if I don't get anywhere, then I'll install Python 2.7 and then Anaconda.

Comment: @PaulH: thank you very much for your Anaconda suggestion! While your comment doesn't answer my specific question, it does solve my issue - trying to use pandas (and other analytics modules) on a 'locked down' VM.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this works, but you could try to install `pip` with this command `easy_install pip` on the terminal, and then use `pip` to update the `numpy` package.

With this command `pip list --outdated` you can see which packages are outdated.

I think that with this command `pip install -U numpy` you can upgrade the `numpy` package.

If you manage to install `pip`, you can also see more about `install` requirements typing `pip help install`.

Comment: If his VM doesn't have access to external hosts, wouldn't `pip` not help?